# Controller registration error while using ng-route

Tags: angular

I am creating an angular application using v1.6.4. I am using ngRoute and have defined a solitary routing condition for now. I created an app.js file for angular module initialization and have a separate folder for other application js files.

app.js:

```
"use strict";

var appOtmReport = angular.module("appReport", ['ngRoute']);

appOtmReport.config(['$routeProvider',function($routeProvider) {

    $routeProvider.when('/home',{
        templateUrl: 'views/reportSample.html',
        controller: 'js/reportSampleController'
    })
    .otherwise({redirectTo:'/home'});
}]);
```

index.html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en"  id="ng-app">
<head>
<meta charset="ISO-8859-1">
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
<meta charset="utf-8">
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">

<title>OTM-DCPP Query Report</title>

<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/bootstrap.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/bootstrap-theme.min.css">

</head>
<body>

<div  ng-app="appReport">
    <ng-view></ng-view>
</div>

<!-- JQuery stuff -->
<script src="lib/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="lib/highcharts.js"></script>

<!-- AngularJS framework stuff -->

<script src="lib/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="lib/angular.min.js"></script>
<script src="lib/angular-route.min.js"></script>

<!-- application specific js -->
<script src="app.js"></script>
<script src="js/reportSampleController.js"></script>


</body>
</html>
```

Controller(separate file in different directory):

```
appOtmReport.controller('reportSampleController',function ($scope){
    $scope.name = "Vikash";
});
```

When I run this, I get the below error:
**[$controller:ctrlreg] http://errors.angularjs.org/1.6.4/$controller/ctrlreg?p0=js%2FreportSampleController(…)**

As a result , I do not get the resolved expression but something like : **Hi Name is :{{name}}**

I have gone through other links similar to this , but none happen to help me. I would be thankful for any help.

Comment: Any help would be very valuable

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found out the issue here. My app.js and controller file were in a different folder, hence the module was inaccessible inside the controller.  Once I moved the app.js file to the same directory as the controller, it worked.

Changed my index.html :

```
<!-- application specific js -->
<script src="**js/app.js**"></script>
<script src="js/reportSampleController.js"></script>
```

changed app.js:

"use strict";

var appOtmReport = angular.module("appOtmDcppQueryReport", ['ngRoute']);

```
appOtmReport.config(['$routeProvider',function($routeProvider) {

    $routeProvider.when('/home',{
        templateUrl: 'views/reportSample.html',
        **controller: 'reportSampleController'**
    })
    .otherwise({redirectTo:'/home'});
}]);
```